# Creating listview filled with mix of manual items and cursor items

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

On my (first) android app, I have a diary screen that shows a list of appointments the user has. Currently the app shows a list of appointments with the core information displayed on the list (start time, end time, etc).

In order for the user to see when they have free time between appointments, they need to painstakingly look at all the times and work out when there is a gap. I would like to create this gap visually to make it more intuitive for the user.

Currently I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill the listview from an SQLite table, but to my knowledge, I cannot edit the results of a cursor (as - it is my understanding - that the cursor is only a pointer to the database, not a copy of the information).

Ideally what I would like to do is detect whenever there is a gap between appointments and insert an extra row where there is a gap (regardless of the size of the gap - just a single row). I would like this 'gap' row to state how many minutes of free time the gap contains.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Edit: I have added my ideal layout below:

[image]

Comment: Actually I cant figure out what is your problem ? please explain me.. Because i think your Que is differ from your Details.. As per your Question you need Custom list view.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me clarify - I want to populate a listview with cursor items (appointments from database) and manually-inserted items (gaps between appointments).

Comment: Okie... So You want to insert manually in list view that item is (gaps between appointments). Am i right?

Comment: Correct :) Any ideas? I'm new to Android

Comment: That entry already there in your database or that also need to insert??

Comment: The manual 'gaps' are not already in database, they need to be added after I run the query, so I know where the gaps are :)

Comment: :) Need logic for that,, I ll try for that and reply you soon :)